# Unable to save data in child activity android studio

Tags: java, android

After entering the details in EditText in child activity when I go back to parent activity and comes back to child activity the EditText value is becoming blank. I have used below mentioned code, but no use.

Below mentioned is childactivity.java details.

Can anyone help in this.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String typedText;
    EditText inputTxt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        typedText = inputTxt.getText().toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        inputTxt.setText(typedText); 
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy the activity even if you are setting `typedText` to something it will become `null` because the next time you launch this activity from other, a new instance will be created and old data will be lost.
You have to store data with persistent storage options.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

To store data in SharedPreferences you can modify following code.

```
private final String PREFS_NAME = "packageName";

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("typedText", inputTxt.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

And to retrieve the value you can do as following.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String typedValue = sharedPref.getString("typedText", "defaultValue/null");
```

Comment: Dear Ranjan, can you please help me to get the complete code for the above mentioned details. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Which persistent storage option to used depends on what kind of data you want to store. Go through the article to read each one's advantages. If you are going to store few values only, you can use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: In child activity there is 1 EditText object with multiple lines. It is like notes. Please suggest for complete code.

Comment: If you are making a notes like app, you should use `SQLite Database`.

Answer (score 0):

In parent call startActivityForResult(getApplicationContext(), NotesActivity.class) to call child activity which is NotesActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        String typedText = "" + extras.getString("TypedText");

    }
}
```

In the Child activity use below function to return 'typedText'

```
private void returnText() {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    String typedText = inputTxt.getText().toString();
    result.putExtra("TypedText", typedText);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
} 


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    returnText();
}
```